# Calculate the total of amount by category in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I make this query :

```
$expenses = Expense::where('team_id', Auth::user()->currentTeam->id)
            ->with(['categories'])
            ->orderBy('entry_date', 'DESC')
            ->get();
```

ExpenseSumByCategoryResource :

```
return [
            'id'         => Hashids::encode($this->id),
            'entry_date' => $this->entry_date,
            'amount'     => $this->amount,
            'category' => $this->category->name
 ];
```

Response :

```
"expenses": [
        {
            "id": "GO3W1MkgWkngpnByQ6",
            "entry_date": "2020-10-14",
            "amount": "50.00",
            "category": "Health"
        },
        {
            "id": "7vK6bz0gnG7JBOYRLD",
            "entry_date": "2020-10-14",
            "amount": "30.00",
            "category": "Uncategorize"
        },
        {
            "id": "7vK6bz0gnG7JBOYRLD",
            "entry_date": "2020-10-14",
            "amount": "30.00",
            "category": "Health"
        },
        {
            "id": "7vK6bz0gnG7JBOYRLD",
            "entry_date": "2020-10-14",
            "amount": "30.00",
            "category": "Food"
        },
    ]
```

I would like to calculate, by category, the sum of "amount".

Ideally, I would like to have a result which is this :

```
"expenses": [
        {
            "category": "Health"
            "total_amount": "80.00",
        },
        {
            "category": "Uncategorized"
            "total_amount": "30.00",
        },
        {
            "category": "Food"
            "total_amount": "30.00",
        },
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding a `select()` and `groupBy()` which makes sense for your query:

```
$expenses = Expense::select('category', DB::raw('SUM(amount) AS total_amount'))
    ->where('team_id', Auth::user()->currentTeam->id)
    ->groupBy('category')
    ->with(['categories'])
    ->orderBy('category')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Hello ! It doesn't work because as shown in my example, I'm using a resource file to call "category"

Comment: I can't help you with that.  See if you can make my answer work somehow.